# Why power set of integer is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Z+ = {1,2,3,4,...}

if we constuct the P(Z+) like that,

0={}

1={1}

2={2},{1,1}

3={3},{1,2}

4={4},{1,3}

5={5} {1,4} {2,3}

6={6} {1,5} {2,4} {1,2,3}

7={7} {1,6} {2,5} {3,4} {1,2,4}

8={8} {1,7} {2,6} {3,5} {1,2,5} {1,3,4}

......
Then we use hilbert hotel to move the "guest" to ensure they are one-to-one response.

Comment: For example the subset $\{1,3,5,7,9,\ldots\}$ is still without a room. The set of *finite* subsets of $\Bbb{Z}_+$ on the other hand is countable.

Comment: Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3114428/11619). LInks to many other related threads there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the power set of the natural numbers countable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77656/is-the-power-set-of-the-natural-numbers-countable)

Comment: Thanks ,It solve my confusion.